# audit report issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, auditing, audit-log-reports

I have configured the Audi report setting for editing items,  it working duly.

Today I changed a `department.aspx`page, opened the audit log report it is not showing the edit entry!

I think there's a service need to restart or timer job

please help me to solve my nut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be aware of the Pages, such as **.aspx**, aren't considered documents so they can't be audited in SharePoint Server 2016.

So I am sure your issue is not related to a specific service or timer job, you can't find the page audit log because of you are trying to edit a page (not a document) `department.aspx` that will not be audited!

For more details check [Configure audit settings for a site collection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-A9920C97-38C0-44F2-8BCB-4CF1E2AE22D2)